# Mapping a field to another ObjectId of different collection in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am just wondering if its possible to use a $lookup aggregation operator inside of the in field of a $map operator. I am trying to map the VINs inside the carData objects to corresponding document ids in a VIN collection. Is there a way to accomplish this using $lookup inside of $map where I can match the vin field inside my carData objects with vin fields inside of my VIN collection to map to an id as opposed to the vin.

```
CarData Collection:

carData: [
 {vin: 123456789,
  make: "Dodge"},
 {vin: 987654321,
  make: "Honda"}
]


Vin Collection:
[
{
   _id: ObjectId("1dsf1234125")
   Vin: 123456789
},

{
   _id: ObjectId("1dsf1234124")
   Vin: 987654321
},

]
```

Expected result

```
carData: [
 {vin: ObjectId("1dsf1234125"),
  make: "Dodge"},
 {vin: ObjectId("1dsf1234124"),
  make: "Honda"}
]
```

Comment: You _cannot_ use an aggregation stage (`$lookup`) inside of the `in` parameter of the `$map` aggregate operator.  I suggest you include samples of both input documents and a sample of expected result too - in your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
db.carDatas.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$carData"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Vins",
      localField: "carData.vin",
      foreignField: "Vin",
      as: "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      make: "$carData.make",
      vin: { $first: "$docs._id" },
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      carData: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2l0_dT1HR7r)

Comment: Is there any way to reassign the object id to the original vin field inside the carData objects?

Comment: @Mark I just don't understand can you edit your question with certain json format that you need.

Comment: @Mark Maybe you need to show a sample of the output you are expecting in your question.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the expected result.

Comment: @Mark I update my answer

Comment: This works, but some of the other fields and values inside of the carData objects are no longer displaying because if the $project. Is there any way to still show the original fields in $project without manually putting all of them?

Comment: @Mark Sure. Please edit your own question with the expected result and test data that you really have and really need.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data samples from the question post, this aggregation returns the expected result (change the collection names appropriately):

```
db.cars_collection.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "vins_collection",
            localField: "vin",
            foreignField: "Vin",
            as: "car_vins"
        }
   },
   { 
      $project: {
          _id: 0,
          make: 1,
          vin: { 
              $arrayElemAt: [ 
                  { $map: { input: "$car_vins", in: "$$this._id" } }, 0 
              ] 
          }
      }
  },
])
```

The result will look like this:

```
{ "make" : "Dodge", "vin" : ObjectId("626a12a1ac1cc4f9d0bbd7e7") }
{ "make" : "Honda", "vin" : ObjectId("626a12a1ac1cc4f9d0bbd7e8") }
```

Comment: Note the ObjectIds in the result are from the vins_collection.